# using openquery to connection to Active directory

Tags: sql-server, active-directory

I have the following code to connect to my active directory and then pull users in a certain group.  As the code is below it works fine, however I have to hard code the department I want to look in.

I am trying to pass a parameter to the openqueries second parameter (second code) but I keep getting an error, I know it's a problem with my quotation marks

```
select *
from openquery(ADSI, '

select
givenName, 
sn, 
sAMAccountName, 
displayName,
mail, 
telephoneNumber, 
mobile, 
physicalDeliveryOfficeName, 
department, 
division


from ''LDAP://DC=directorysync,DC=cfc, DC=com'' 
where objectCategory = ''Person'' 
and objectClass = ''user''
and department = ''Production''
AND displayname <> ''0_UW_Template_Remote''
ORDER BY displayName
')



select *
from openquery(ADSI, '

select
givenName, 
sn, 
sAMAccountName, 
displayName,
mail, 
telephoneNumber, 
mobile, 
physicalDeliveryOfficeName, 
department, 
division


from ''LDAP://DC=directorysync,DC=cfc, DC=com'' 
where objectCategory = ''Person'' 
and objectClass = ''user''
and department = '''+@Department+'''
AND displayname <> ''0_UW_Template_Remote''
ORDER BY displayName
')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot construct the query within the `openquery` call, you'll need to build the query in a variable then execute it.

```
declare @qry varchar(8000)
set @qry = 'select *
from openquery(ADSI, ''
    select
    givenName, 
    sn, 
    sAMAccountName, 
    displayName,
    mail, 
    telephoneNumber, 
    mobile, 
    physicalDeliveryOfficeName, 
    department, 
    division


    from ''''LDAP://DC=directorysync,DC=cfc, DC=com'''' 
    where objectCategory = ''''Person'''' 
    and objectClass = ''''user''''
    and department = '''''+@Department+'''''
    AND displayname <> ''''0_UW_Template_Remote''''
    ORDER BY displayName
'')'

exec(@qry)
```