# LDAP query to use variable when querying for displayName in Active Directory

Tags: sql, active-directory

After reading this thread [using openquery to connection to Active directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184670/using-openquery-to-connection-to-active-directory) I've found a way for my variable substitution into an LDAP query to parse, but it's not returning results. (just column headings).

```
declare @name nvarchar(100)
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

set @name = 'Sanjay*'
set @sql=
'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (
ADSI,
''SELECT givenname ,
sn,
displayname,
samaccountname,
telephonenumber,
mail,
department,
title
FROM ''''LDAP://domainobfuscated''''
WHERE 
objectClass = ''''USER'''' 
and objectCategory = ''''person''''
and displayName = ''''+@name+'''''')'

exec dbo.sp_executeSQL @sql
```

But when run like this it returns these results:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (
ADSI,
'SELECT givenname ,
    sn,
    displayname,
    samaccountname,
    telephonenumber,
    mail,
    department,
    title

FROM  ''domainobfuscated''

WHERE     
objectClass = ''USER'' 
and objectCategory = ''person''
and givenName = ''Sanjay*''')
```

How can I get it to run the query instead of returning the query?